# How can I duplicate "upper-canvas" with FabricJS?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I am using FabricJS in a React app and I am simply rendering an image on a canvas.

Here is my react component:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import {fabric} from "fabric";
import maptest from '../assets/images/maptest.jpeg';

function getDivDimensions() {
  const {innerWidth: width, innerHeight: height} = window;
  return {
    width,
    height
  };
}

function Mapblock() {
  const [height, setHeight] = useState(0);
  const [canvas, setCanvas] = useState(null);
  const initCanvas = () => (
    new fabric.Canvas('c', {
      height: calcHeight(),
      width: calcHeight()
    })
  );

  function calcHeight() {
    let divHeight = document.getElementById('mapDiv').clientHeight;
    return divHeight;
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    function handleResize() {
      setHeight(calcHeight);
    }

    setCanvas(initCanvas());
    window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);
    return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize);
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("canvas effect", canvas);
    if (!canvas) {
      return
    }
    canvas.on('mouse:wheel', function(opt) {
      var delta = opt.e.deltaY;
      var zoom = canvas.getZoom();
      zoom *= 0.999 ** delta;
      if (zoom > 15) zoom = 15;
      if (zoom < 0.5) zoom = 0.5;
      canvas.zoomToPoint({ x: opt.e.offsetX, y: opt.e.offsetY }, zoom);
      opt.e.preventDefault();
      opt.e.stopPropagation();
    });

    let image = new fabric.Image(document.getElementById('image'), {
      left: 0, top: 0
    });
    image.lockMovementX = true;
    image.lockMovementY = true;
    image.selectable = false;
    canvas.setDimensions({
      width: image.width, height: image.height
    })
    canvas.add(image);
    canvas.renderAll();

  }, [canvas])
  return (
    <div id="mapDiv" className="overflow-y-clip">
      <canvas id="c"></canvas>
      <img id="image" src={maptest} className="hidden"/>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Mapblock;
```

However the generated div for the canvas is this:

```
    <div id="mapDiv" className="overflow-y-clip">
      <div className="canvas-container" style="width: 626px; height: 626px; position: relative; user-select: none;">
        <div className="canvas-container" style="width: 1600px; height: 1600px; position: relative; user-select: none;">
          <canvas id="c" className="lower-canvas" width="1600" height="1600"
                  style="position: absolute; width: 1600px; height: 1600px; left: 0px; top: 0px; touch-action: none; user-select: none;"></canvas>
          <canvas className="upper-canvas " width="1600" height="1600"
                  style="position: absolute; width: 1600px; height: 1600px; left: 0px; top: 0px; touch-action: none; user-select: none; cursor: move;"></canvas>
        </div>
        // duplicate redundant upper-canvas
        <canvas className="upper-canvas " width="626" height="626"
                style="position: absolute; width: 626px; height: 626px; left: 0px; top: 0px; touch-action: none; user-select: none; cursor: default;"></canvas>
      </div>
      <img id="image" src="/static/media/maptest.64a5034fde914bdc70c2.jpeg" className="hidden canvas-img"/>
    </div>
```

The duplicate `upper-canvas` is not letting a certain area of the canvas be zoomable.

So where is this coming from and how do I fix it?

Comment: I am facing the same issue with fabric in my next.js app
I am also finding solution to this

Comment: @NikunjSardhara I decided to altogether discard fabric js and use konva js instead. Check that library out. It has more downloads than fabric on npm. And that definitely for a reason!

Comment: I am using Next.js and I disabled server side rendering in Next.js and it fixed my issue. Yes, Konva.js is a good library.

Answer (score 1):

The same thing happened to me with NextJS. What happens is that when the new version of React is in development mode the useEffects run twice. See here why they do it: [https://www.youtube.com/ watch?v=j8s01ThR7bQ](https://www.youtube.com/%20watch?v=j8s01ThR7bQ).

That's why running the same code twice duplicates it on canvas.

Cheers